# How to merge two Doubly Linked Lists (Accessing next link)

Tags: c++, linked-list, doubly-linked-list

I am trying to merge two doubly linked lists.  I created a function already that inserts a new node and in the correct order.  The parameters are set by my professor so I can not change them.  I am able to add the first item to List1 but am unable to add anymore.

I am getting errors while trying to continue to traverse List2 and add more items to List1.  I have tried recursion and a do while loop.  While trying to use a do-while loop

```
struct nodeType{
int info;
nodeType *next;
nodeType *back;
};

class OrderedDoublyLinkedList{
public:
    //Insert x in appropriate place in the list to keep it 
    sorted
    void insertNode(int x);
    void mergeLists(OrderedDoublyLinkedList &List1, 
    OrderedDoublyLinkedList &List2);

private:
    int count;
    nodeType *first;
    nodeType *last;
};

void 
OrderedDoublyLinkedList::mergeLists(OrderedDoublyLinkedList 
&List1, OrderedDoublyLinkedList &List2){

//First Technique
do{
    List1.insertNode(List2.first->info);
    List2.first->next; //Error: Expresion result unused
}
while(List2.first!=NULL)

//Second Technique
while(List2.first!=NULL)
    List1.insertNode(List2.first->info);
    mergeLists(&List1, &List2.first->next);
//If I try to use this it says cannot bind to a temporary of 
type
```

I need help accessing the next node to add the rest of the info to List1.

Comment: Let's start with the basics, what does *merge two lists* mean? For instance are you trying to create a third list by merging two lists? Are you trying to merge the second list onto the first (or the other way around)? Very often the word merge means that the nodes are one list are moved (not copied) onto another list, i.e. no new nodes are allocated and the second list is destroyed by moving nodes onto the first. Is that the case here? These details matter, so you really need to specify exactly what you expect `mergeLists` to do. Add some examples of the inputs and outputs that you expect.

Comment: One issue which you don't address in your two attempts is that the merged list should be *ordered*. So any solution to this problem needs to compare nodes on the first list with nodes on the second lists, so it can maintain the correct ordering. So somewhere in your code you need to compare the `info` fields of the two lists.

Comment: I have to move List2 into List1.  The insert function creates the new node and then puts it in the correct order already so no need for comparing

Comment: OK, that's very inefficient, but I guess it's what you've been told to do.

Comment: I didn't include that function because I did not want it to be too lengthy.  Right not I am mostly worried about trying to access the next link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a simple while loop is all you need

```
nodeType* n = List2.first;
while (n != NULL)
{
    List1.insertNode(n->info);
    n = n->next;
}
```

Although I'm still worried whether this is an acceptable solution. You said that you need to **move** `List2` into `List1`, and that's not what this code does, This code **copies** `List2` onto `List1`, `List2` is unaffected by this code.

Comment: Thank You very much.  Why am i unable to use List2.first->next?

Comment: I also have a delete function function that I am able to use get rid of the elements in List 2 if needed

Comment: Like your warning says `List2.first->next;` does nothing. It's like the difference between `cout << 2 + 2;` and `2 + 2;`. Both expressions calculate something, but only the first does something with that calculation. `List2.first->next` calculates what the second node in `List2` is, but then does nothing with that information.

Comment: Will try it in a second , but If I would have done List2=List2.first->next would that have been acceptable

Comment: @MichaelTorres No because the types are incorrect, `List2` is type `OrderedDoublyLinkedList` and `List2.first->next` is type `nodeType*`. You're confusing the nodes of the list with the list itself. If you want to iterate over the list you need to work with the nodes themselves. That's what my `n` variable is doing in the code above.